# How to convert multiple staff id to name in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

[image]

This is my index page where I want to get name by ids. if there is single id in `Staff_id` column than it show but if their is multiple id than it only show first one

```
@foreach($assignments as $assignment)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('assignments.complete', $assignment->id) }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            @if ($assignment->done_at == null or $assignment->done_at = '')
                                <button type="submit" name="submit">incomplete</button>
                            @elseif ($assignment->done_at !== null)
                                <button type="submit" name="submit">Complete</button>
                            @endif
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{$assignment->id}}</td>
                    <td>
                            {{$assignment->staff->name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{$assignment->task->title}}</td>
                    <td>{{$assignment->task->description}}</td>
                    <td>{{$assignment->task->done_at}}</td>
                    <td>{{$assignment->task->created_at}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('assignments.destroy',$assignment->id) }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            @method('delete')
                            <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        @endforeach
```

[image: It showing like this]

It showing like this``

Comment: what version you are using? cause  you tagged [tag:laravel-4] , [tag:laravel-5]  [tag:laravel-8]

Comment: use `JSON Encode` and `for` loop

Comment: I am using laravel-8

Comment: How can i do I not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Blade file first, you need to convert string to array

```
@php 
  $staff = $assignment->staff_id;
  $staff_ids = explode(",",$staff_name); //converted to array
  print_r($staff_ids); //here you can check 
@endphp

<td>
@foreach ($staff_ids as $value)
    {{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}
    <span class="nice">{{ $value->name }}</span>
@endforeach
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally id write a mutation on the assignment model, e.g.

```
getStaffNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->staff()->first()->name;
}
```

which can be used like so

```
$assignment->staffName
```

but you could just do

```
$assignment->staff->first()->name;
```

I may be missing parenthesis in this.

Also this is only if you actually made them related... and not just manually entered in ID's in a column.... which i have a feeling you did...

*EDIT*

Showing how the many relation works.

On the assignment model you would have this

```
public function staff()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Staff::class);
}
```

and on the staff model you would have

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Assignment::class);
}
```

This relation would require a pivot table called `assignment_staff` with `assignment_id` and `staff_id`  How you name the pivot tables are alphabetical order with singular names e.g. A comes before S so its assignment_staff not staff_assignment.

The reason its many to many as one assignment can have many staff and each staff can belong to many assignments.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Can you explain how this relationship will be ? He has multiple ids so how are you creating this relationship ?

Comment: The question is, he is not using any pivot table, he is storing staff_ids as comma separated. So your updated answer is still not to the point.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir na the question was how to access the first staff member. my answer is still correct. he just has a poorly designed database.

Comment: It's not poorly designed, this scenario has been used by expert developers too. He has showed you the staff_id in a screenshot with comma separated, the answer should be according to that question for future developers understanding bro. Your answer is your suggestion not correct answer in this case.

Comment: The amount of work that your database would need to do for a reverse lookup of staff members assignments, its poorly designed. face it.